# right and left CSS attributes not working properly with input-group bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, css-position

I have a search input. I used `input-group` in **Bootstrap 4**. Now, I want to position this element as absolute positioning with `left` and `right` attributes. Curiously, only one of these attributes will work but not both. Any ideas why is this happening and solutions?

Here is a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Maged_Saeed/hse2kr4c/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lj1mg7wa/1/)**

```
.search-group {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 50px !important;
    bottom: 5px;
    width: calc(100% - 100px)
}
```

Add `width: calc(100% - 100px)` in your css. `right:50px` is also working. But, in your `.input-group` class has `width:100%`. So, it won't work as expected.

Comment: thanks for this solution. It will work with width attribute, but why not working with `right`?

Comment: @MagedSaeed `right` is also working. https://jsfiddle.net/cuj0vxqg/ . It didn't work because of `width:100%` in `.input-group` class